# WordPress - Permalink isn't working locally

Tags: wordpress, xampp, http-status-code-404

I've been trying to run a website made on WordPress locally.
For some reason I can only see the 'Home' page, when I switch to another page running it locally it gives me this error (in Spanish):

[image]

Why does that happen? It works fine from the server using the original domain, but when I run it locally then that happens.

I'm using Xampp to run it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your .htaccess file, and set the permalink again from wp-admin

Comment: I deleted .htaccessfile from both wp-content/uploads/wc-logs and  wp-content/uploads/seo_wizard-redirects is that right? And what did you mean by setting the permalink again from wp-admin?

Comment: Delete the .htaccess in the website root folder. Then open wordpress backend, go to settings->permalinks, select permalink structure, then save changes

Comment: YOU AREEE MY SAVIORRR!! Thank you so much you just saved my butt.